# how to stop CSS hyphenation, no dash between words

Tags: css

How do I stop words becoming hyphenated

e.g: 
Supercalifragilis-
ticexpialidocious

should just be Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

tried the css below from CSS Tricks but it doesnt seem to be working, especially on safari. any help???

```
 -ms-word-break: break-all;
 word-break: break-all;

 // Non standard for webkit
 word-break: break-word;

 -webkit-hyphens: auto;
 -moz-hyphens: auto;
 hyphens: auto;
```

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: hi, i tried that but its just doing one long line that overflows - not what i was expecting tbh. thanks tho

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try

```
-webkit-hyphens:manual;
-moz-hyphens:manual;
hyphens:manual;
```

putting them on auto is causing the issue

also you can completely turn them off using

```
  -moz-hyphens: none;
  -ms-hyphens: none;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
```