# CSS/JS - Overriding font-size if the word is too long for the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I have a series of containers that each contain a word, occasionally two words.

CSS

```
.container-title {
  font-size: 5.625vw;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-title">Orange</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-title">Acai Berry</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-title">Kiwi</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-title">Mangosteen</div>
</div>
```

These all look perfect, except for "Mangosteen" that ends up as "Mangoste-en". I don't mind title with two words, but want to avoid any one-word title from being hyphenated. Would it be best to override this in JS to fix the issue, or is there a CSS method that would work?

Comment: have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348820/how-to-stop-css-hyphenation-no-dash-between-words/20348920). This might help you

Comment: Can the word wrap around? Is smaller font the only option?

Comment: @wazz I've tried all of the methods posted, so far it still shows on 2 lines. It definitely looks like adjusting to a smaller font is the only option, assuming that using JS would be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in CSS3.0:

```
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```